# How to execute javascript files after files are loaded

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have multiple js files, I use Head.js library to load them at the same time before the page gets a load, but I still get an error that one tends to get when one is ordered incorrect, so one function is trying to call for function in other file but that file is not loaded yet, so it results in undefined...

How do I ensure that all files are load, so they are ready to be used? Do I really need to order them every time I have new files?

HTML

```
<script src="/Head.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Loader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The loader is where I load all my files, the head is a library for the said loader.

Loader JS

```
var Arts = '/Game Projects/The Grand Hunt CYOA/Arts/Style.css'

var jQuery = '/jQuery.js'

var Intro = '/Game Projects/The Grand Hunt CYOA/Events/Introduction.js'

var System = '/Game Projects/The Grand Hunt CYOA/Systems/System.js'

var Equipment = '/Game Projects/The Grand Hunt CYOA/Characters/Player/Equipment.js'

var Inventory = '/Game Projects/The Grand Hunt CYOA/Characters/Player/Inventory.js'

var Store = '/Game Projects/The Grand Hunt CYOA/Systems/Store.js'

var Random_Encounter = '/Game Projects/The Grand Hunt CYOA/Systems/Random Encounter.js'

var Map = '/Game Projects/The Grand Hunt CYOA/Systems/Map.js'

var Stat = '/Game Projects/The Grand Hunt CYOA/Characters/Stats.js'

head.load(Arts, jQuery, Intro, System, Equipment, Inventory, Store, Random_Encounter, Map, Stat, function(){
    console.log('loading completed')
});
```

***`Console Log`***

```
Introduction.js:13 Unknown

Random Encounter.js:209 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'

Stats.js:41 max is 100
Stats.js:42 current is 0
Stats.js:44 level is 1
Stats.js:45 Stat Points is 0
Stats.js:58 max is 100
Stats.js:59 current is 0
Stats.js:61 level is 1
Stats.js:62 Stat Points is 0

Loader.js:22 loading completed

Map.js:1471 Your location is GM_A_Tutorial
System.js:24 
Map.js:1706 Using (4,4) as Starting Location.

System.js:71 Your Movement is now false for next function call, but you lost the ability to move for this function call.

**jQuery.js:3734 jQuery.Deferred exception: ERG is not defined ReferenceError: ERG is not defined
    at startGame (http://127.0.0.1:5500/Game%20Projects/The%20Grand%20Hunt%20CYOA/Events/Introduction.js:83:3)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:5500/Game%20Projects/The%20Grand%20Hunt%20CYOA/Events/Introduction.js:50:3)
    at mightThrow (http://127.0.0.1:5500/jQuery.js:3461:36)
    at process (http://127.0.0.1:5500/jQuery.js:3526:21) undefined**

jQuery.Deferred.exceptionHook @ jQuery.js:3734
process @ jQuery.js:3529
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ jQuery.js:3561
fire @ jQuery.js:3204
fireWith @ jQuery.js:3330
fire @ jQuery.js:3338
fire @ jQuery.js:3204
fireWith @ jQuery.js:3330
ready @ jQuery.js:3786
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ jQuery.js:3806
(anonymous) @ jQuery.js:34
(anonymous) @ jQuery.js:38

**jQuery.js:3740 Uncaught ReferenceError: ERG is not defined
    at startGame (Introduction.js:83)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (Introduction.js:50)
    at mightThrow (jQuery.js:3461)
    at process (jQuery.js:3526)**

startGame @ Introduction.js:83
(anonymous) @ Introduction.js:50
mightThrow @ jQuery.js:3461
process @ jQuery.js:3526
setTimeout (async)
jQuery.readyException @ jQuery.js:3739
(anonymous) @ jQuery.js:3755
mightThrow @ jQuery.js:3461
process @ jQuery.js:3526
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ jQuery.js:3561
fire @ jQuery.js:3204
fireWith @ jQuery.js:3330
fire @ jQuery.js:3338
fire @ jQuery.js:3204
fireWith @ jQuery.js:3330
process @ jQuery.js:3544
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ jQuery.js:3561
fire @ jQuery.js:3204
fireWith @ jQuery.js:3330
fire @ jQuery.js:3338
fire @ jQuery.js:3204
fireWith @ jQuery.js:3330
ready @ jQuery.js:3786
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ jQuery.js:3806
(anonymous) @ jQuery.js:34
(anonymous) @ jQuery.js:38

Map.js:1740 Something special on this tile.
```

The error that is annoying me is ones in bold, the other one can be fixed.

It says that it is not defined.

Yet it is defined in file Random Encounter, and on top of the pyramid, so it shouldn't be inside anything that might prevent it from being seen by the Intro file...

```
function ERG() { // Enemy Random Generator
    // Enemy will have three structures to form their form. Body, Name, and Element,
    // Body decide their species and whatever they are capable of talking or mob or smart, etc.
    // Name decide their name, their title will be mixture of their element and body which can decide their personality.
    // Their element is their power such as darkness, light, fire, earth, tech, psi, etc. it also influence their personality.
    
    let E_B = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1) // Enemy Body
    console.log('E_B '+E_B)
    let E_N = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1) // Enemy Name
    console.log('E_N '+E_N)
    let E_E = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1) // Enemy Element
    console.log('E_E '+E_E)

    //console.log('currentland is '+currentland)

    if (currentland == 'A_Tutorial') {
        EC(E_B, E_N, E_E);
    }

    function EC(E_B, E_N, E_E) { // Enemy Creation

        if (E_B == 1) {
            E_B = "Cultist"
            console.log(E_B)
        }
        if (E_B == 2) {
            E_B = "Cosmic Horror"
        }
        if (E_B == 3) {
            E_B = 
        }

        if (E_N == 1) {

        }
        if (E_N == 2) {

        }
        if (E_N == 3) {

        }

        if (E_E == 1) {

        }
        if (E_E == 2) {

        }
        if (E_E == 3) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: At the moment, the error is resolved by reordering the loading into this:

head.load(Arts, jQuery, Random_Encounter, System, Map, Intro,  Equipment, Inventory, Store, Stat, function(){
    console.log('loading completed')
});

But soon or later, I would not be able to reorder them since they will end up rely on others to do their job, I only have a multi-file system so I can find what I am looking for easier by organizing rather than clump them into 1 big file... True, I probably can just use

//#region (Insert Name Here)
//#endregion

But surely, there is a way to do this...

Comment: I have facing similar error like you. It's probably because failed to load. I fixed the error by reloading the page. For example, if there is several object those are `math`, `$`, `highlight`, `Chart` I solve by `try {math; $; highlight; Chart} catch(err) {location.reload()}`.  Unfortunately, it will take longer time to reload the page.

Comment: I will keep that in mind when the amount of files I have is getting too large to order without error.

Comment: Typo???  Your error: `Random Encounter.js:209 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'`.  Your code: `if (E_B == 3) { E_B = }`.  Set E_B to something.

Comment: Oh, man. I focus load javascript files not the sources. He is also declare native function `Map`. `var Map = '/Game Projects/The Grand Hunt CYOA/Systems/Map.js'`.

Comment: @HoldOffHunger Yeah, I am well aware of that. It is when this problem fails to detect other stuff that I pause it and didn't finish it, Which is why I state that the other one can be fixed.

Comment: @Transamunos So was I suppose to use declare it another variable beside Map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I got the answer. I have made function to solve this problem using load event. Event load runs after the element has been loaded. There is also `DOMContentLoaded` runs after the Content has been loaded (not media, such as images, videos, sounds). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event

```
function loadScript(src, fn, type="text/javascript") {
  var e = document.createElement("script"),
  cs = document.currentScript,
  ce = document.body || document.querySelector("head");
  if (fn) e.addEventListener("load", fn);
  e.type = type;
  e.src = src;
  if (cs) cs.parentElement.insertBefore(e, cs);
  else ce.appendChild(e);
}
//Example using the function
loadScript("js/chart.bundle.min.js", function(){
  loadScript("js/chartjs-plugin-labels.min.js",function(){
    new Chart(bar, config.bar)
  })
});
```

Okay, I am response for the "cumbersome". I will make it easier with recursive.

```
function callAScripts(srcs, fn) {
  //srcs is an array files javascript and fn is function
  function loadScript(src, fn) {
    var e = document.createElement("script"),
    cs = document.currentScript,
    ce = document.body || document.querySelector("head");
    if (fn) e.addEventListener("load", fn);
    e.src = src;
    if (cs) cs.parentElement.insertBefore(e, cs);
    else ce.appendChild(e);
  }
  if (srcs.length) {
    if (srcs.length == 1) {
      loadScript(srcs[0], fn)
    } else {
      loadScript(srcs[0], function(){callAScripts(srcs.slice(1, Infinity), fn)})
    }
  }
}
```

It's using recursive method, which call it self. For example:

```
function f(n) {
  if (n < 2) return 1;
  return n*f(n-1);
}
```

But, the code `callAScripts` is more complex than the example.

Comment: Thank you for the effort, but it doesn't seem to solve it, altogether, it works fine if I just order loadScript in the right order, but that the same as if I order var inside the head.load the right way. As I have stated before, this method will become cumbersome to do so once I have many files to work with. But it is entirely possible I am doing your way wrong.

Comment: loadScript(System, function(){
    console.log('System loading, completed')
});

The loadScript is the same as yours. It does not work if order in wrong way, rendering it useless once my files reach point where I cant no longer add file or edit file as they will now rely on each other, making it impossible to order them as they need each other.

Comment: Farther look at your comment make me think that there may be misunderstanding and you thought that I was looking for source of head.load and reorganized it into javascript. Which is not what I was asking for, sorry. I was just want to see if it possible to load files and have them interact with each other after everything is loaded, so it wont end in error of not see function or variable because it have not been load in yet.

Comment: I think you're having problem on checking your codes. If you're using android , I suggest use Acode https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.foxdebug.acodefree. It's have checking error, console and free. For desktop, I recommend visual studio. All is up to you.

Comment: I am using visual studio, but no such luck, it clearly a case of file load before other files, so it can't do something because it is not there at that moment of reading code. All I need to do is reorder code and ensure that I do not ask for something that should not be there at the moment such as start combat from prologue can lead to an error because map and functions for combat are not load in at the start of the game just because I want to test combat and not other stuff. If I play it from the beginning, then it works fine enough.